# process dialog not showing asynctask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days, i would like the progresdialog to show but it isn't showing. When I login i want the asyncHttpTask to show and dismiss the processdialog, which doesn't happen.

The clicklogin method in my Activity Login

```
@OnClick(R.id.login)
public void clickLogin() {

    if ((!etUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!etPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
        boolean succesfullLogin=new UserFunctions().
              loginUser(etUsername.getText().toString(),
              etPassword.getText().toString(),Login.this);
        if(succesfullLogin){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{

        }


    } else if ((!etPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if ((!etUsername.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Username field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Username and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The loginuser in class userFunctions which calls the async task

```
  public Boolean loginUser(String username, String password, Login context) {
    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("url", loginURL);
    map.put("username", username);
    map.put("password", password);

    AsyncHttpTask loginTask = new AsyncHttpTask(pDialog);

    try {
        HttpObject response = loginTask.execute(map).get();


        if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            JSONObject json = response.getJsonObject();


            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

            Log.i("json user:", json.getString("username"));

            /**
             * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
             **/
            UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
            logout.logoutUser(context);
            //db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
              //      json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME), json_user.getInt(KEY_AGE), json_user.getInt(KEY_NRCHILDREN),
                //    json_user.getString(KEY_CIVILSTATUS), json_user.getString(KEY_SEX), json_user.getInt(KEY_VEGETARIAN) == 0 ? false : true);


            Log.i("succes", "succesfull log in");
            return true;


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.i("errormessage", "Incorrect username/password");
        }


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return false;
}
```

And Finally the AsyncHttpTask which Extends Asynctask

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Integer, HttpObject> {


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private HttpObject httpObject;
private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;


public AsyncHttpTask(ProgressDialog pDialog) {
    this.pDialog = pDialog;
    httpObject = new HttpObject();
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
    pDialog.show();
}


@Override
protected HttpObject doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    try {
        buildConnection(params[0]);

        httpObject.setResponseCode(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        if (httpObject.getResponseCode() == 200) {

            buildJson(new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        }


    }  catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("HttpTask:",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpObject;
}




private void buildConnection(Map<String, String> urlMap) throws IOException {


    URL url = new URL(urlMap.get("url"));
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    for (String key : urlMap.keySet()) {
        if (key != "url") {
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty(key, urlMap.get(key));
        }

    }

    Log.i("HttpTask", urlConnection.toString());
    Log.i("HttpTask", url.toString());


}

private void buildJson(BufferedInputStream is) {
    String json = "";
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        Log.i("json in string: ", json);
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        Log.i("json in string: ", json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    httpObject.setJsonObject(jObj);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpObject httpObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(httpObject);
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: `HttpObject response = loginTask.execute(map).get();`  If that line of code worked, the task wouldn't be asynchronous now, would it?  Look up some AsyncTask tutorials to see how you should structure your program.

Comment: yes that was the problem indeed. My fault for copy pasting to much code without fully understanding what it does, i feel pretty stupid now.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me not understanding asynctask

this was what i was doing wrong:

```
HttpObject response = loginTask.execute(map).get()
```